# How do I verify the RS256 signature attribute of a webhook in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rsa

I've been trying to solve this issue for the past two days and it's sending me a little loopy. I hadn't looked into Cryptography much before then so I'm very confused trying to figure out what I'm meant to do.

I've been working on integrating APIs from a payment provider known as Citizen. Some of the steps of the payment process send webhook updates to my endpoint in the following format:

```
 "eventType":"<the event type of a webhook>",
 "paymentToken": {
      "id": "<token ID>",
      "paymentProvider": "<paymentProvide e.g. LLOYDS>",
      "paymentMethod": "<internal marker>",
      "paymentGiro": "<the payment giro used e.g. FPS/SEPA>",
       ...other data omitted for brevity
    },
    "signature": "token-signature."
}
```

And their documentation only advises the following:

All webhook updates will contain a signature of the token details which you can verify by the using of our public key.

For signing we use SHA256 with RSA. You can get the public RSA key from "https://api.citizen.is/v1/entities/citizen-signing-public-key (or testapi.citizen.is for test)"
The signature can be found with the "signature" attribute of the webhook update.

I've retrieved the public key but I'm confused as to which part of the message I'm supposed to verify. All the other examples I've found the signature is in the header and so all of the request body is hashed to verify the signature. Am I supposed to remove the signature and hash the rest of the message? I've tried that but it's still returning false. I have what I've got so far down below, any help would be appreciated!

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
        {
            using var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body);
            // You now have the body string raw
            var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignedWebhook>(body);
            var originalMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OriginalWebhook>(body);
            var result = VerifyData(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(originalMsg), Convert.FromBase64String(msg.signature));

            return new OkResult();

        }

        public static bool VerifyData(string originalMessage, byte[] signature)
        {
            string stringpublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzIU140G9rFe6ouNFuhCxIj3Ps3ELUV9w4XTnDsti8kcSTXMf0z6LMNVIqXaZYFbSYXAZRmuM3XNmoSWmMZzPBMl2/C7uC0wyNdrYdPw0uzU2wfr8MQbnvW0yQgQ/cSHNDUZR+n/s2ipXTdNmbRd4z+k+qXxw00xMDmiJu5iMHyYo24x284lTZ3+4dgL4xFlrtjgcb/NGHBpVPQTCbBfEQcmylCwzbTUdBJlAo5ezpziOJ6CNf9FDS1hvRKRvNl7Hx8To6vQZJTwdCT5RWDC2JYL0oSdPV+SZmlfHQQe33p81MiRl4cjp5AwMVKyAosDihGT810WFYhK431EIB/NR/wIDAQAB";
            string pemPublicKey = $"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n{ stringpublicKey }\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

            var pkey = ImportPublicKey(pemPublicKey);
            var signatureDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(pkey);

            // Set the hash algorithm to SHA256.
            signatureDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
            byte[] hash;
            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                hash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalMessage));
            }

            bool verified = signatureDeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, signature);


            return verified;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import PEM public key string into MS RSACryptoServiceProvider
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pem"></param>
        /// <returns>RSACryptoServiceProvider</returns>
        public static RSACryptoServiceProvider ImportPublicKey(string pem)
        {
            PemReader pr = new(new StringReader(pem));
            AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pr.ReadObject();
            RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)publicKey);

            RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new();// cspParams);
            csp.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
            return csp;
        }
```

The endpoint is being reached and I'm able to set the public key but after that I have no idea what I'm supposed to do next.

Comment: You should really ask Citizen this. There's no way for anyone to know if they haven't documented it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like they are probably signing the paymentToken, not the entire message.  Perhaps try something like this:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body);
        // You now have the body string raw
        var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignedWebhook>(body);
        var originalMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OriginalWebhook>(body);
        var result = VerifyData(Convert.FromBase64String(msg.paymentToken), Convert.FromBase64String(msg.signature));

        return new OkResult();
    }

    public static bool VerifyData(byte[] paymentToken, byte[] signature)
    {
        string stringpublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzIU140G9rFe6ouNFuhCxIj3Ps3ELUV9w4XTnDsti8kcSTXMf0z6LMNVIqXaZYFbSYXAZRmuM3XNmoSWmMZzPBMl2/C7uC0wyNdrYdPw0uzU2wfr8MQbnvW0yQgQ/cSHNDUZR+n/s2ipXTdNmbRd4z+k+qXxw00xMDmiJu5iMHyYo24x284lTZ3+4dgL4xFlrtjgcb/NGHBpVPQTCbBfEQcmylCwzbTUdBJlAo5ezpziOJ6CNf9FDS1hvRKRvNl7Hx8To6vQZJTwdCT5RWDC2JYL0oSdPV+SZmlfHQQe33p81MiRl4cjp5AwMVKyAosDihGT810WFYhK431EIB/NR/wIDAQAB";

        var signingCert = new X509Certificate2(stringpublicKey);

        var keyParams = signingCert.GetRSAPublicKey().ExportParameters(false);
        var rsa = RSA.Create();
        rsa.ImportParameters(
            new RSAParameters()
            {
                Modulus = keyParams.Modulus,
                Exponent = keyParams.Exponent
            }
        );            

        bool verified = rsa.VerifyData(paymentToken, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        return verified;
    }
```

Comment: It's not worked but thanks for your help your code really helped clarify a lot of things for me and you've completely removed my need for the BouncyCastle library. I think the issue is to do with the payment token I don't know if I have the correct properties set up in my class so I've reached out to Citizen for more information on that but thanks a lot for your assistance! :)

Comment: Glad it helped!  That "paymentToken" value is definitely the thing that you have to figure out what goes there.